# Getting error "Argument 'fn' is not a function, got <controllerName>"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm writing test cases for a directive in my application. Please see the code below.

```
describe('Note component', function () {
    var $rootScope, $compile, $controller;
    beforeEach(module('templates'));
    beforeEach(module('home'));
    beforeEach(module('note'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$log_, _$window_, _$controller_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $log = _$log_;
        $window = _$window_;
        $controller = _$controller_;

        elHome = angular.element("<home-component></home-component>")
        $compile(elHome)($rootScope.$new())
        elNote = angular.element("<note-component></note-component>")
        $compile(elNote)($rootScope.$new())

        $rootScope.$digest()
        noteController = elNote.controller("noteComponent")
        homeController = elHome.controller("homeComponent")
        notescope = elNote.isolateScope() || elNote.scope()
        homescope = elHome.isolateScope() || elHome.scope()

    }));

    it('should save note', function () {
        notescope.saveNote();
        expect($log.debug.logs[0]).toEqual(['Saving note started']);
        expect($log.debug.logs[1]).toEqual(['Note saved successfully']);

    });

    it('should delete note', function () {
        notescope.deleteNote();
        console.log($log.debug.logs)
    });

});
```

this is returning error

```
Argument 'fn' is not a function, got noteController
```

If anyone of the `it` is removed, it works fine. Means if either 'should save note', or 'should delete note' is removed, there won't be any error.
Why is this happening ?

Comment: after the execution of second "it". I put debug point for the closing brackets. till there no error.

Comment: Probably easiest to enable interactive debugging with a browser on the tests so you can see the stack trace and figure out how you are getting to the error and why.